# Linear constraints as cone generators.

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-programming

In linear programming problems, the usual form is

minimize $ \sum c_j x_j$

subject to $\sum_{j=1}^n {\bf a_j} x_j = {\bf b}$

and $x_j \geq 0$.

where ${\bf a_j }$ are column vectors. Now, here my professor said:

The collection of vectors of the form $\sum_{j=1}^n {\bf a_j} x_j $ where $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n \geq0$ is the ${\bf cone}$ generated by the vectors ${\bf a_1}, {\bf a_2}, ..., {\bf a_n}$.

Im really not understanding how is this true. Perhaps am I getting this concept wrong?

Comment: The two concepts are equivalent. For further information: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given vectors $\mathbf{a}_1,\dotsc,\mathbf{a}_n$, you can refer to the sum $\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{a}_ix_i$, with $x_i \ge 0$ for $i = 1,\dotsc,n$ as their [conical combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conical_combination).
As explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_cone), such a combination generates a cone, which is the collection of all the terms $\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{a}_ix_i$ with non-negative $x_i$'s.

If you take any two constraints $\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{a}_ix_i = \mathbf{b}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{a}_iy_i = \mathbf{c}$, their sum $\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf{a}_i(x_i+y_i) = \mathbf{b} + \mathbf{c}$ is still a constraint (it happens to be less informative though). In this sense, the space of your constraints is a cone.