# how to draw the space of such linear combinations?

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces, intuition, visualization, convex-geometry

We have the linear combination

$$ {2 \choose 1 } x_1 + {1 \choose 2} x_2 + {1 \choose -2} x_3 + {1 \choose 1} x_4 + {-1 \choose 0 } x_5 + {0 \choose -1 }x_6 $$

As $x_i \geq 0 $ is given, according to the definition, the linear combination above generates a cone. But, how can we draw it? Isnt the linear combination above just the entire $\mathbb{R}^2$ plane?

Also, I need to decide whether the vector ${6 \choose 4}$ lies in the cone, but since the linear combination above represesnt the entire plane, then ${6 \choose 4}$ must lie in.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: can you give reference to your definition?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2904483/linear-constraints-as-cone-generators

Comment: $ {2 \choose 1 } \cdot 4 + {1 \choose 2}\cdot 0+ {1 \choose -2} \cdot 0 + {1 \choose 1}\cdot 0 + {-1 \choose 0 }\cdot 2+ {0 \choose -1 }\cdot 0 =  {6 \choose 4 }$.

Comment: I thought adding the tags of Convex geometry, intuition, visualization would be a good idea, want to reverse it, do tell me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to illustrate Yves' answer: in the below figure the original points are drawn in blue. The blue polygon is their [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull). As Yves rightly pointed out, the origin (black) is inside this convex hull. To draw the cone, you now need to inflate this blue convex hull. This is illustrated by the red polygon. You will notice that you will ultimately end up with the whole plane when you keep on inflating the convex hull. Hence, the cone you are looking for is indeed the whole plane and since ${6 \choose 4 }$ is obviously in the whole plane, it is also in the cone. Hope this helps.

[image: Convex hull of the points]

Comment: what is a convex hull?

Comment: The convex hull of a set of points is smallest convex set which contains all of the points. A set is called convex if for any two points in the set the line between those two points lies completely in the set. This implies that one property of a convex set is that it has no holes.

Comment: So, to draw the convex hull, we just plot the point and join them to form a polygon? How about the point (1,1)?

Comment: You have to join them and make sure at the same time that the resulting polygon will be convex. Notice that (1,1) lies inside the interior of the convex hull. If you joined any of the other points to (1,1) and used the line between the two as an edge of the polygon, the resulting polygon would not be convex. 
For example, if the edges of the polygon were drawn from (-1,0)~(1,1)~(1,2)~(2,1)~(1,-2)~(0,-1)~(-1,0) then this polygon would not be convex because the line between (-1,0) and (1,2) would not lie inside the polygon.

Answer (score 2):

A possible way is as follows:

- Let's call the vectors $v_1={2 \choose 1 }, v_2 ={1 \choose 2}, v_3={1 \choose -2}, v_4 = {1 \choose 1}, v_5={-1 \choose 0 }, v_6={0 \choose -1 }$
- Excluding the trivial case $x_1 = \ldots = x_6 = 0$ note that
- $S = \sum_{i=1}^6x_i > 0 \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^6\frac{x_i}{S}v_i$ is a convex combination of the given vectors.
- So, the convex hull of the given vectors $\{v_1, \ldots , v_6\}$ must lie in the cone.
- If this covex hull contains an open ball around ${ 0\choose 0 }$ - which is the case - then the "cone" is the whole plane, because any positive multiple of the elements of this convex hull must lie in the cone, as well.

Answer (score 2):

If $\max(u,v)\lt0$, then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}=(-u)\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\end{pmatrix}+(-v)\begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\end{pmatrix}
$$
If $\max(u,v)\ge0$, then
$$
\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\end{pmatrix}=\max(u,v)\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}+\max(v-u,0)\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\end{pmatrix}+\max(u-v,0)\begin{pmatrix}0\\-1\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You are right. As the origin lies inside the convex hull of the vectors, any point can be reached.

Comment: how can we draw that cone by hand?

Comment: Draw the points, draw the hull and inflate it.

Comment: hmm... why the downvote?

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh: thanks for the solidarity ;-)

Comment: Not just a downvote. Someone (probably whoever downvoted it) suggested that this answer should be deleted.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: the honeymoon downvoter strikes back...

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh I am not the downvoter, and I would not downvote this answer, but a downvote does not seem outrageous to me. It's a one-line answer, with little explanation. It took another answer to explain properly this idea. Unfortunately the "fastest gun in the West" phenomenon causes many people to write short answers here, but that's not always in the best interest of this site.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: my personal policy is to write answers as short as I can (without sacrificing meaning) and to stick to the essential. Some will prefer a more tutorial approach. My motivation is certainly not getting reputation, I already got my tee-shirt ;-)